# Pattern for global interaction updates?

Tags: python, game-engine

I'm using Python and the BGE to build a cellular automata "game".  I have a world that Automata wander through.  If they get within a certain distance of each other, I'd like them to decide to greet or ignore the other.  I'm looking for the right pattern for that.

Each automata has its logic controlled by `Automata.py` with a class within it.  The world has spawners in `World.py`.  What is the best way to iterate over all possible pairs within distance `d` of each other.  My initial model is to have a set `automata = []` with everyone in it, then do a double loop.

```
for me in automata:
  for you in automata[me:]:
    if distance(me, you) < d:
       if me.decide_to_greet():
         me.greet()
```

Is it better to make this a routine in `world` or done per automata?  Are there accepted, efficient patterns?

thanks!

Comment: I think that if they are automata, then you should use a near sensor and loop per automata when the sensor is activated. Related :[https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88019/bge-object-list-within-a-specified-distance/88040#88040](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88019/bge-object-list-within-a-specified-distance/88040#88040)

Comment: Okay, the automata level then.  Thanks for the feedback I'll try it.

Comment: Also, this doesn't sound like _cellular_ automata. As far as I know, cellular automata are like [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) – see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton). (: